# Does $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n/(n-1)!$ converge to something?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I just ran into an expression, and I would like to know what it converges to.
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{n}{(n-1)!}$$

Do you know if it converges to something (like $e$) or, in alternative, how to find out what it converges to?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the equation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n-1+1}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(n-2)!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(n-1)!} = e + e = 2e$$

Comment: Wow, that was fast.

Comment: Curse you for typing faster! *shakes fist*

Comment: That was fast indeed!

Comment: Damn neutrino typists.

Comment: Or if $g(x)=xe^x$, then $g'(1)=2e$, and $g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-1)!}x^n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}$, so $g'(1)$ gives the series in question.

Comment: Any faster the answer would have come before the question!\